# Why initializing in this way gives compile time error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This may seem something silly but can any one tell me why the below code is giving error ?

```
    class Program
{
    static int abc;
    abc = 110;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(abc);
    }
}
```

But if I do the initialization like this, it runs !

```
    class Program
{
    static int abc = 110;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(abc);
    }
}
```

Comment: initialization of class members has to go with declaration.  You've effectively got "code" outside a method which is not valid.

Comment: @DStanley: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a static initializer to do what you're wanting to do (if not just assigned inline), otherwise you need to assign it in a constructor or method.

```
    class Program
{
    static int abc;

    static Program(){
       abc = 110;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(abc);
    }
}
```

Check this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I made an edit for c# syntax.  See the link provided for any additional syntax questions.

Answer (score 1):

The line `abc = 110` is not within a method body.  You can initialize the variable at declaration, but you cannot have a line of code that makes that assignment outside of a method body.  The class file is invalid.